# CreateOleObject in a 64-bit Delphi program?

Tags: delphi, ole, delphi-xe7

In a Delphi XE7 **64-bit** VCL program, the unit `Vcl.OleAuto`cannot be found:

`[dcc64 Fatal Error] Unit1.pas(33): F1026 File not found: 'Vcl.OleAuto.dcu'`

While it works without problems in a **32-bit** program:

```
uses
  Vcl.OleAuto;
...
FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
```

So how can I use `CreateOleObject` in a **64-bit** program?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Although the source code for `Vcl.OleAuto` is still supplied, the 64 bit `lib` directory does not include `Vcl.OleAuto.dcu`. Instead you are expected to use `System.Win.ComObj` and/or `System.Win.ComServ`. Note that the source for `Vcl.OleAuto` marks that unit as being deprecated, and tells you what to use instead.

If we look through the source for `Vcl.OleAuto` we can find some 32 bit asm code that has not been ported. Presumably Embarcadero decided not to port this to 64 bit because the unit is deprecated.